# Elements positionning with CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I have some difficulties in positioning the circle element as in this picture:

[image: webpage circle elements]

```css
.cercle_ourwork {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #E1E1E1;
  position: relative;
}

.orange_border_ourwork {
  width: 9vw;
  height: 9vw;
  border: 3px solid #FF591E;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="our_work">
  <div id="size_ourwork">
    <div class="cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Could you help figure out how can I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried using css-grid for this?

Comment: I've tried, but i can't figure out how to implement the two middle element with css grid. I will try Daniel Rodriguez solution.

Comment: Did it worked? with grid i guess you have to use a span, as a colspan, and i think you could also use colunms too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class for each position, apply margins for each position.
if you wanna use text is the same principle, just give more margins and apply the same logic to spacing the text.

```css
.cercle_ourwork.upper {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #E1E1E1;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 12vw
}

.cercle_ourwork.left {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #E1E1E1;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

.cercle_ourwork.right {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #E1E1E1;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 15vw;
}

.cercle_ourwork.bottom {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px #E1E1E1;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 12vw;
  margin-top: 6vw;
  
}

.orange_border_ourwork {
  width: 9vw;
  height: 9vw;
  border: 3px solid #FF591E;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 4%;
}
```

```html
<div id="our_work">
  <div id="size_ourwork">
    <div class="upper cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom cercle_ourwork">
      <div class="orange_border_ourwork">
      </div>
    </div>
```